# Variation of Gauss-Bonnet Invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, variational-calculus

I am trying to do the variation of Gauss-Bonnet Invariant, and the Gauss-Bonnet Invariant is:

$G$=$R^2$+$R_{abcd}$$R^{abcd}$-$4R^{ab}$$R_{ab}$

The variation of $G$ is:

$\delta$$G$=$2R\delta$$R$+ $\delta($$R_{abcd}$$R^{abcd}$)-$\delta$$(4R^{ab}$$R_{ab}$)

I am having problem in doing the variation of $\delta($$R_{abcd}$$R^{abcd}$).

Can anyone please give me the solution in detail? I have the answer but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great exercise and I provide my solution here. You will need to use the following formula, but I will not provide a proof.

1. $\delta g_{\mu\nu} = - g_{\mu\rho} g_{\nu\sigma} \delta g^{\rho\sigma}$
2. $\delta \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu} = -\dfrac{1}{2} [g_{\lambda \mu} \nabla_{\nu}(\delta g^{\lambda \sigma}) + g_{\lambda\nu} \nabla_{\mu}(\delta g^{\lambda \sigma}) - g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}\nabla^{\sigma}(\delta g^{\alpha \beta})]$,
3. $\delta R^{\mu}{}_{ \nu\rho\sigma} = \nabla_{\rho}(\delta \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\sigma}) - \nabla_{\sigma}(\delta \Gamma^{\mu} _{\nu\rho})$

Then back to the orignal problem,

$$
\begin{align*}
\delta (R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}) &= R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}+R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\\[.2cm]
&=R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta (g^{\mu a}g^{\nu b}g^{\alpha c}g^{\beta d}R_{abcd}) + R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\\[.2cm]
&=R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}(g^{\nu b}g^{\alpha c}g^{\beta d}R_{abcd}\delta g^{\mu a} + g^{\mu a} g^{\alpha c}g^{\beta d}R_{abcd}\delta g^{\nu b} + g^{\mu a}g^{\nu b}g^{\beta d}R_{abcd}\delta g^{\alpha c} + g^{\mu a}g^{\nu b}g^{\alpha c}R_{abcd}\delta g^{\beta d} +g^{\mu a}g^{\nu b}g^{\alpha c}g^{\beta d}\delta R_{abcd}) + R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\\[.2cm]
&=2R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} + R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}(R_a{}^{\nu\alpha\beta}\delta g^{\mu a} + R^{\mu}{}_b{}^{\alpha\beta}\delta g^{\nu b} + R^{\mu\nu}{}_{c}{}^{\beta}\delta g^{\alpha c} + R^{\mu\nu\alpha}{}_{d} \delta g^{\beta d})\\[.2cm]
&=2R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} + R_{\mu}{}^{\nu\alpha\beta}R_{a\nu\alpha\beta}\delta g^{\mu a}+ R_{\nu}{}^{\mu\alpha\beta} R_{b\mu\alpha\beta}\delta g^{\nu b} + R_{\alpha}{}^{\beta \mu\nu} R_{c\beta\mu\nu}\delta g^{\alpha c} + R_{\beta}{}^{ \alpha\mu\nu} R_{d\alpha\mu\nu}\delta g^{\beta d}\\[.2cm]
&= 2R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} + 4R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta \gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta \gamma} \delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&= 2R^{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma} g_{\mu\nu}\delta R^{\nu}{}_{\alpha\beta \gamma} + 2R^{\mu\alpha\beta \gamma}R^{\nu}{}_{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta g_{\mu\nu} + 4R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta \gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta \gamma} \delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&=2R_{\nu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta R^{\nu}{}_{\alpha\beta \gamma}-2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta g^{\mu\nu} + 4R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta \gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta \gamma} \delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&=2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta R^{\mu}{}_{\alpha\beta \gamma} + 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta \gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta \gamma} \delta g^{\mu\nu}
\end{align*}
$$
Let us analyze the first term. Using the two formulas mentioned at the beginning, we can get,
$$
\begin{align*}
R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta R^{\mu}{}_{\alpha\beta\gamma}&= R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}(\nabla_{\beta} \delta \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\gamma} - \nabla_{\gamma} \delta \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\beta}) \\[.2cm]
&= 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma} \nabla_{\beta}\delta \Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha\gamma}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that we have used the property $R^{\mu}{}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} = -R^{\mu}{}_{\alpha\gamma\beta}$. Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta R^{\mu}{}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} &= 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma} \nabla _{\beta} \left[-\frac{1}{2}g_{\lambda\alpha}\nabla_{\gamma} \delta g^{\lambda \mu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\lambda \gamma} \nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\lambda \mu} + \frac{1}{2}g_{\alpha \rho} g_{\gamma\sigma}\nabla^{\mu}\delta g^{\rho\sigma}\right]\\[.2cm]
&=R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\left[-g_{\lambda\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}\nabla_{\gamma}\delta g^{\lambda\mu} - g_{\lambda \gamma}\nabla_{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}\delta g^{\lambda\mu} + g_{\alpha\rho} g_{\gamma\sigma} \nabla_{\beta}\nabla^{\mu} \delta g^{\rho\sigma}\right]\\[.2cm]
&=-\underbrace{{R_{\mu\lambda}{}^{\beta\gamma}}\nabla_{\beta} \nabla_{\gamma}\delta g^{\lambda\mu}}_{0} - R_{\mu\alpha\beta \lambda}\nabla^{\beta}\nabla^{\alpha} \delta g^{\lambda \mu} + R_{\mu\rho\beta \sigma} \nabla ^{\beta }\nabla^{\mu}\delta g^{\rho\sigma}\\[.2cm]
&=-2R_{\mu\alpha\beta\lambda} \nabla ^{\beta} \nabla^{\alpha} \delta g^{\lambda \mu}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that in the last step we also take advantage of the antisymmetry of $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ with respect to the first two indices. Rewrite the dummy indices and use Leibniz's rule to get
$$
\begin{align*}
R_{\mu} {}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\delta R^{\mu} {}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} &= -2R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}\nabla^{\beta}\nabla^{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&=-2\nabla^{\beta} (R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu})+2(\nabla^{\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}) (\nabla^{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu})\\[.2cm]
&=-2\nabla^{\beta} (R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu}) + 2\nabla^{\alpha}(\delta g^{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\beta} R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}) - 2(\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla^{\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu})\delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&=- 2(\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla^{\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu})\delta g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\lambda} j^{\lambda}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\nabla_{\lambda} j^{\lambda}$ is a total divergence,
$$
\color{blue}{
\nabla_{\lambda} j^{\lambda} = -2\nabla^{\beta} (R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu}\nabla^{\alpha}\delta g^{\mu\nu}) + 2\nabla^{\alpha}(\delta g^{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\beta} R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu})
}
$$
Substituting the results we obtained back into the initial expression, we can get the final variational result:
$$
\begin{align*}
\delta (R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}) &=- 4(\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla^{\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu})\delta g^{\mu\nu} + 2\nabla_{\lambda} j^{\lambda} + 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta \gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta \gamma} \delta g^{\mu\nu}\\[.2cm]
&=\boxed{\color{red}{\left(-4 \nabla^{\alpha}\nabla^{\beta} R_{\mu\alpha\beta\nu} + 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha\beta\gamma}R_{\nu\alpha\beta\gamma}\right)\delta g^{\mu\nu} + 2\nabla_{\lambda}j^{\lambda}}}
\end{align*}
$$
The red part is the final result we get.

Hopefully my answer is of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta \Gamma^c_{ab} &=  \frac{1}{2}  \left( \nabla_a h_b{}^c + \nabla_b h_a{}^c - \nabla^c h_{ab}  \right) ~, \\
\delta R^a{}_{bcd} &= \frac{1}{2}  \nabla_c \nabla_d h_b{}^a +  \frac{1}{2}  \nabla_c  \nabla_b h_d{}^a -  \frac{1}{2}  \nabla_c  \nabla^a h_{db}   -\frac{1}{2}  \nabla_d \nabla_c h_b{}^a   -\frac{1}{2}  \nabla_d  \nabla_b h_c{}^a + \frac{1}{2}  \nabla_d  \nabla^a h_{cb}    ~, \\
\delta R_{ab} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \nabla_c \nabla_a h_b{}^c + \nabla_c \nabla_b h_a{}^c - \nabla^2 h_{ab} - \nabla_a \nabla_b h \right)  ~, \\
\delta R &= - R_{ab} h^{ab} + \nabla_a \nabla_b h^{ab} - \nabla^2 h ~, \\
\delta \det g &=  h \det g  ~. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $h_{ab} = \delta g_{ab}$ and $h=g^{ab} h_{ab}$.

Comment: I actually know this but what next?

Comment: My question is that how to solve $\delta($$R_{abcd}$$R^{abcd}$) further?
In solution I have something like $-4R_{acbd}$$R^{cd}$ .... etc

Comment: Can you please give me the detail of it?
I am actually trying to derive the field equations of $f(R,G)$ gravity and I am stuck at this point

Comment: +1, the curvature at any local point is indeed the global invariance of divergence. It also satisfies Ergodium Thereom with the determinants at the end.