# Writing a gravity equation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, spacetime-dimensions

I need a maple cod to variation this action with respect to tensor metric $g_{\mu\nu}$.

This called the Einstein equation. To obtain the Einstein equation, we vary the action with respect to the metric tensor.

Where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $R_{\mu\nu}$  is a Ricci tensor, $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ is a Riemann tensor, $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor, $\alpha(\varphi)$ is a function of $\varphi(r)$, $\varphi$ is a scalar field and function of r , $R_{GB}$ is a quadratic Gauss-bonnet (GB) term, and ($\mathrm{d}^{4}x$) represents the volume element in four-dimensional spacetime.

$$ S = \int \mathrm{d}^{4}x\,\sqrt{-g}[R + \alpha(\varphi)R_{GB} + \lambda(g_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\varphi\partial_{\nu}\varphi\pm1)]$$
[image]

Note: $S$ is action in GR
you can see the result in this paper :

[arXiv:1812.06941v1 [hep-th]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06941v1) 17 Dec 2018

Comment: *I need a maple cod* Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Comment: Can I ask why you need a code for this instead of doing this by hand?

Comment: You may find [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368965/variation-of-gauss-bonnet-invariant) useful.

Comment: I recommend learning xAct (http://xact.es/), a Mathematica package for tensor algebra for doing these (and more complex) calculations.